# c# Group a list and get the count of each group

Tags: c#, linq, list

I have a list of strings with multiple entries of the same value. I need to get all unique elements in the list as well as the count of each unique element group.
For example:

```
        string a = "cat";
        string b = "dog";
        string c = "cat";
        string d = "horse";

        List<string> list = new List<string>();

        list.Add(a);
        list.Add(b);
        list.Add(c);
        list.Add(d);
```

I need this data: "cat"--2, "dog"--1, "horse"--1

Comment: Using Linq, look at the GroupBy extension method. e.g. list.GroupBy(x => x)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to do a GroupBy:

```
var result=list.GroupBy(s=>s).Select(g=>new{Animal=g.Key, Count=g.Count()});
foreach(var e in result)
   Console.WriteLine("{0}--{1}",e.Animal,e.Count);
```

If you want you can do the same removing the call to the `Select` extension method:

```
var result=list.GroupBy(s=>s);
foreach(var g in result)
   Console.WriteLine("{0}--{1}",g.Key,g.Count());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 List<string> list = new List<string>() { "cat", "dog", "cat", "horse" };
 var groupedResult = list.GroupBy(x => x).Select(y=> new{item = y.Key , count=y.Count()}) ;
```